# Weakened associativity axiom: $(x * y) * z \leq x*(y*z).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, examples-counterexamples

Call a partially ordered magma $(X,*)$ *sub-associative* iff it satisfies the following axiom. $$(x*y)*z \leq x*(y*z).$$

Basically, this is saying that we may shuffle brackets right to get a larger $(\geq)$ expression, or left to get a smaller $(\leq)$ expression.

I'm looking for:

1. Interesting examples, especially those "from the wild."
2. The standard name for these kinds of structures, if such a name exists.

*Near-example.* Every distributive lattice satisfies the following. $$(x \vee y) \wedge z \leq x \vee (y \wedge z)$$

*Motivation.* In any such structure $(X,*)$ we can shuffle brackets around to get lower and upper bounds on an expression. For example, consider the following expression.

$$(x*y)*(x'*y')$$

We get the following lower and upper bounds, respectively.

$$((x*y)*x')*y',\quad x*(y*(x'*y'))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this sub-associative property (that does seem like a good name) recently when I was thinking about ordered structures and enriched categories.

Let $(X,*)$ be a magma with a partial order $\leq$ such that we have $x*z\leq y*z$ and $z*x\leq z*y$ for all $z\in X$ whenever $x\leq y$ in $X$. I am assuming this is what you mean by a 'partially ordered magma'. Also suppose that there is a function $d\colon X\times X\to X$ satisfying
$$\tag1
x*y\leq z\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x\leq d(z,y)
$$
for all $x,y,z\in X$. In other words, this condition says that for each $y\in X$ the multiplication function $-*y$ has an [upper adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#.28Monotone.29_Galois_connection), which we denote $d(-,y)$. If the other multiplication function $y*-$ also had an upper adjoint then it would be fair to call $X$ a '[residuated magma](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gy46SP7px7gC&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false)', but let's not assume that as well.

I have written '$d$' for the upper adjoint of the multiplication function (this is non-standard notation) because we want to think of it as a very weak kind of "distance function". Specifically, we will assume that $d$ satisfies
$$\tag2
d(x,y)*d(y,z)\leq d(x,z)
$$
for all $x,y,z\in X$. This condition is motivated by the triangle inequality in a metric space and the composition morphism in an enriched category ([this nLab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#lawvere_metric_spaces) describes the connection between these two notions).

I now claim that $X$ has the sub-associative property.

> **Proof:** Let $x,y,z\in X$. Since $x*(y*z)\leq x*(y*z)$ we have $x\leq d(x*(y*z),y*z)$ by (1), and similarly since $y*z\leq y*z$ we have $y\leq d(y*z,z)$ by (1). Now since $\leq$ is compatible with $*$ in the sense described above (i.e., since $X$ is a partially ordered magma) we have
>   $$x*y\leq d(x*(y*z),y*z)*d(y*z,z),$$
>   and as such $x*y\leq d(x*(y*z),z)$ by (2). Finally, by (1) again we have $(x*y)*z\leq x*(y*z)$, as required.

An interesting feature of this set-up is that sub-associativity appears to be the best we can do. That is, even if we were to assume equality in (2), it seems impossible to derive the other sub-associativity inequality. Note, however, that if we had assumed that the other multiplication function also has an upper adjoint satisfying (2) then we would obtain $x*(y*z)\leq(x*y)*z$ for all $x,y,z\in X$ (and hence genuine associativity) by a similar proof.

Comment: Looks interesting, although a bit over my head. Any ideas where I can get a bit more information?

Comment: This combines quite a few ideas, and some of them are not so easy to find about online unfortunately. To get a feel for what ordered structures satisfying condition (1) above are like I would suggest reading about [residuated lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice). There is quite a lot written about these structures, and they are relevant because every residuated lattice has an underlying partially ordered magma. But the magma and partial order are special because the multiplication is actually associative and the order is actually a lattice.